# Change Devexpress export row value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult ExportTo(ExportFormat exportFormat = ExportFormat.Xlsx)
    {
        ExportType exportType = GridViewHelper.ExportTypes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Format == exportFormat);

        if (exportType != null)
        {
            var modelList= modelRepository.GetAll();

            var gridviewSettings = CreateExportGridViewSettings();
            if(gridviewSettings != null)
                return exportType.Method(gridviewSettings, modelList);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ...

    private GridViewSettings CreateExportGridViewSettings()
    {
        var settings = new GridViewSettings
                           {
                               Name = "Export",
                               CallbackRouteValues = new {Controller = "MyController", Action = "List"},
                               Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
                           };

        settings.Columns.Add("Id", Resources.Id);

        !!! ---- !!!

        ...
     }
```

!!! ---- !!! <- Here I want to add column. the row output in this column must be YES if value is True and NO if value is False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
settings.Columns.Add(set =>
                    {
                        set.FieldName = "IsSomething";
                        set.Caption = "Is Something";
                        set.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.String;
                        set.UnboundExpression = "Iif([IsSomething]==True, 'Yes', 'No')";
                    });
```